# Каким образом можно реализовать перетаскивание(DragAndDrop) элементов списка

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть у меня собственно OservableCollection привязанный к ListView

и задача сделать перетаскивание элементов этого Листа вверх/вниз для смены их очередности, а я ума не приложу каким способом это можно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться готовым решением, например [GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop)

Подключите библиотеку из NuGet ([gong-wpf-dragdrop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)).

Подключите в окне пространство имен `xmlns:dd="urn:gong-wpf-dragdrop"`, теперь установка двух свойств просто включает возможность захвата элементов в списке и возможность их приема:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В библиотеке есть возможность установки шаблона перетаскиваемого элемента:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionMode="Extended"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
    <dd:DragDrop.DragAdornerTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"
                    Background="Yellow" Padding="5" CornerRadius="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dd:DragDrop.DragAdornerTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это конечно хорошо и если не получится сделать более красиво я возьму этот вариант. Нужно что бы элемент схватился и проследовал за мышкой весь т.е. как из браузера картинка когда ее тянешь со своего места

Comment: Изучите ссылку на гит, там есть примеры с шаблоном перетаскиваемого элемента

Comment: Добавил простейший пример